Required Field Missing Error on Landing Page
I'm encountering the following error when I'm trying to publish landing page:
Error Message: "Call to create the salesforceobject Account failed! Error status code: REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING Error message: Required fields are missing: [LastName]"

I'm attempting to create a person account. The error only occurs when I pass the last name parameter. However, when I hardcode the last name, the record saves successfully, and the landing page creates the account as intended.
AmpScript with Error:
%%[
set @email = RequestParameter("email")
set @fname = RequestParameter("firstName")
set @lName = RequestParameter("lastName")
set @phone = RequestParameter("mobilephone")
set @Leadid = RequestParameter("Leadid")

/*Inserting Account record in Salesforce */

set @RecordTypeId = "0122v000000jtfc"
var @accid
set @accid=CreateSalesforceObject("Account", 5,"LastName",@lName,
                "FirstName",@fname,
                "PersonMobilePhone",@phone,
                "PersonEmail",@email,
                "RecordTypeId", @RecordTypeId)
]%%

This works perfectly:
set @accid=CreateSalesforceObject("Account", 5,"LastName","Test Last Name",
                "FirstName",@fname,
                "PersonMobilePhone",@phone,
                "PersonEmail",@email,
                "RecordTypeId", @RecordTypeId)


Are you sure lastName is sent correctly to this landing page through the url parameters? In your place, I’ll start by printing the value of lName to the screen first to be sure .. it’s dumb but double check the naming in both pages..

I'm getting this error when I'm trying to publish the landing page.

Based on your latest comment, I can see that the Cloudpage hasn't been published but you were checking in the preview mode. So you need to publish the page to test functionality.
The script in the in the preview mode is still executed due to the action is outside MC.
I would recommend you put a check condition so to be sure it can receive the parameters properly. Something like this:
%%[
set @email = RequestParameter("email")
set @fname = RequestParameter("firstName")
set @lName = RequestParameter("lastName")
set @phone = RequestParameter("mobilephone")
set @Leadid = RequestParameter("Leadid")

/*Inserting Account record in Salesforce */

set @RecordTypeId = "0122v000000jtfc"
var @accid

if Empty(@lName) then
  set @message = "Your exception message."
else  
  set @accid=CreateSalesforceObject("Account", 5,"LastName",@lName,
                  "FirstName",@fname,
                  "PersonMobilePhone",@phone,
                  "PersonEmail",@email,
                  "RecordTypeId", @RecordTypeId)

  set @message = "Person account is created successfully."                  
]%%
%%=v(@message)=%%

